# Getting the outer context of a Meteor Template

Tags: meteor

I have the following use-case: There are rooms which have beds inside. (Bummer...)

There is a loop of rooms which uses a template "room".

```
<template name="rooms">
    {{#each availableRooms}}
        {{> room}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

This template gets for each iteration a room. This is accessible by this.

```
<template name="room">
<div class="room-outer">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list-{{_id}}">
        {{name}} : {{getBeds this}} beds free.
    </button>
    <div id="list-{{_id}}" class="collapse in room-inner">
        {{#each guests_id}}
            <div class="bed">
                <div class="blanket">
                {{showUser this}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Now I like to calculate some special value which I do by extending the template. I need now to pass the this variable to the getBeds function. Is it possible to do this by grabing outside the template and get the room into the function?

```
Template.room.getBeds = function (room) {
    if (room.guests_id)
        return room.beds - _.size(room.guests_id);
    else
        return room.beds;
};
```

Basically I don't want to have to write {{getBeds this}} but only {{getBeds}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this work?

```
Template.room.getBeds = function () {
    if (this.guests_id)
        return this.beds - _.size(this.guests_id);
    else
        return this.beds;
};
```

See the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com#templates):

> Helpers can take arguments, and they receive the current template data in `this`:

Comment: Hi Rahul, This works nicely! Might I ask a follow-up question? I had also Template.room.getFreeBeds = function (room) {return _.range(Template.room.freeBeds(room));}; based on the before. Am I able to set the this from outside?

Comment: Or is there a better place for the more data centric getBeds() function?